# How to add milestones in amCharts using dataLoader

Tags: amcharts

Is there a way to implement new milestones via data feed from database? I checked the example below but couldn't figure out

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/time-line-chart-date-based-milestones/

I use "dataLoader" to feed the values into graphs I can just create a new column in my table for the milestones question is how to update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The milestones in that example are [`guides`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide), so they don't normally get updated in any process that modifies the chart's dataProvider. You can use the [`complete` callback](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#user-content-using-callback-functions) to create/update your chart guides:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  dataLoader: {
    url: "...",
    complete: function(chart) {
      //add/modify guide objects through chart.valueAxes[0].guides or
      //directly to the chart object through chart.guides
      chart.valueAxes[0].guides = [{ 
        "value": new Date(2016, 2, 5),
        "label": "MILESTONE #1",
        "position": "top",
        "fontSize": 15,
        "tickLength": 15
      },
      // .. etc
      ];
      chart.validateData(); //redraw chart
    }
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement it to my charts! Can I define array items to guides too ? as in graphs using "valueField": ?

Comment: No there isn't any valueField-like functionality with guides. You have to create them directly in the array. If your milestone information is in your data, just loop through your data and create them.

Comment: Another question I have related to this, I get the milestones data and chart data through two different json, is it possible to have multiple dataLoader url's?

Comment: No, the serial chart dataLoader supports only one URL.If you need to use multiple URLs, then you should write your own AJAX routines that gets both sets of data first before passing them along to the chart